# Get value in a table1 column with the column name is value in table2

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table, table2 has `nameColumn` that include name of table1 column like

table 1

```
id|check|status|...|
1 |abc  |1     |...|
```

table2

```
|nameColumn|...|
|check     |...|
|status    |...|
```

I want get value in table1 with column name is value in table2 like

```
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `id` = 1 ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die (mysql_error ());
$rowTable = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $s = "SELECT * FROM table2";
$r = mysqli_query($conn,$s);
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
           $columnName = $row1['nameColumn'];
           $value = $rowTable["'".$columnName."'"]; // fail why?
           //$value = $rowTable['check']; // working? 
    }
```

I don't know why `$value = $rowTable["'".$columnName."'"];` fail the error like

```
Notice: Undefined index: 'check' ...
```

But if i using direct like `$value = $rowTable['check']; // working why?`

How to fix that thanks

Comment: Why you add this $rowTable["'".$columnName."'"];. This one no need. It should like that $rowTable[$columnName];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its failing because your adding unnecessary `'` char to it. try the code below

```
 $value = $rowTable[$columnName];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       $value = $rowTable['".$columnName."'];
```